# Making two objects distance time dependent and not range dependant

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a game, where you climb up walls and obstacles come down towards you:
[image]

I made the obstacle movement work with following code:

```
public class ObstacleSpawn : MonoBehaviour {

    public PlayerScript pScript;
    public ObstacleScript oScript;

    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject obstacle;

    public float randomSpawnMin;
    public float randomSpawnMax;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", 2F, Random.Range (randomSpawnMin, randomSpawnMax));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () { 

    }

    void Spawn() {
        if (pScript.isRight == true && pScript.inAir == false) {
            obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1, 1, 1);
            Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3 (0.05F, (4F + pScript.playerDimensionY + oScript.obstacleDimensionY) * Time.deltaTime, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        } else if (pScript.isRight == false && pScript.inAir == false) {
            obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
            Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3 (-0.05F, (4F + pScript.playerDimensionY + oScript.obstacleDimensionY) * Time.deltaTime, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

As can be seen, I use the Instantiate to decide where my obstacle spawns. Currently it's set to spawn at the player location + my Vector3. For my Y-axis I decided to put in 4F + playerDimensionY and obstacleDimensionY, which are half the sizes of my sprites, so the distance is from the bottom of the obstacle and top of the player, instead of the sprite origins.

This works as it should, but I'm creating this game for the purpose of reaction testing. I need the obstacle to spawn fixed amount of seconds away. 1 seconds away, .5 seconds away etc.

How do I achieve this? I tried measuring the length compared to the speed it moved down, but without success. It currently moves by 4 Unity units.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set you off in the right direction :  ( add this to the obstacle's update function) :

```
var seconds = 5f; // <- 5 seconds to reach the bottom of the screen.
var screenheight = ?? ( depends if you are using NGUI, Sprites, or wharever, I suggest using SCreen.height and fitting the size of the objects to fit that ) 
var speed = new Vector3( 0f, -screenheight*Time.deltaTime*seconds, 0f ); // now it takes 5 seconds to reach the position of the player if  he is sitting at the bottom.
obstacles.transform.position = obstacles.transform.position + speed;
```

Comment: I tried running the game with your answer. It did not change anything what so ever. It basically spawns on the player. Should I add obstacle.transform.position somewhere in my Instantiate?

Comment: You need to add it to ObstacleScript and the initialize seconds to sometihng when you spawn the object .

Comment: I apologize for my lack of knowledge, but if I need to initialize seconds, shouldn't it be required to be a global variable, and not inside the Update() function? Or am I misunderstanding what you mean by initializing?

Comment: Yes, you need to put it as a public variable in ObstacleScript if you want to configure ti to something else than 5.

Comment: After trying a few things, I don't believe your suggestion works. My current screenheight is 800 px. Multiplying this with my Y axis deltaTime, the speed the triangle moves south is just multiplied by 800, creating an insane unusable speed. Am I going somewhere wrong here?

Comment: You woulld have to scale everything in the world accordently , as I write it depends on whatever techique that you use for rendering the objects esssentially you will need to scale the world so that the height is 800 units.